# how to handle Simultaneous modification on same csv file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have code in node.js which will read CSV file using fast-csv.

This CSV file is generated by another node application (X) where I do not have any control over it.

X will write data in this file.

What if X will try to write and my code will try to read at the same time?

Questions:

1. Will my code give exception in this scenario?
2. If yes what should be the approach to handle this?

I tried to check if file is open or not

```js
fs.open('/Users/meenalyengul/Documents/fotsWorkspace/fots/lib/newDemo/files/test.xlsx', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
  if (err && err.code === 'EBUSY') {

  }
});
```

this code is not working on mac.

Comment: The short answer is that this is literally why we invented databases.

Comment: Try to answer these few questions to get relevant help: 1) Is this file growing continuously? at some point is this file closed?
1) how big can this file be?
2) How does the program know the name of the file?
3) when can you start reading this file? do you have a callback endpoint?
4) Are you the one launching this X program?

Comment: This varies a bit by OS.  In Windows, if the writer to the file opens it in exclusive mode (preventing anyone else from opening it for read/write), then you will get an error when you try to open it and you would probably want to implement some sort of retry algorithm.  If the other app doesn't open it in such an exclusive mode, then you're just got a concurrency problem and, as the other commentor said, this is what databases are good at, not flat files.  Probably, you need to write a test app to see exactly what the behavior is when the two processes both try to access the file same time.

Comment: @jfriend00 EBUSY check is working in windows but not on mac.

Comment: @Eric 1. program X will write to this file anytime with bunch of data. but not continuously. I am not sure whether this file is closed or not.
2. in this file it may have 100 records.
3. file name is configurable. My code is cron job which will run in every 15 minutes.
4. I don't have any control on program X

Answer (score 0):

You've described a situation where there is no good solution.  On the Mac platform, there is apparently no exclusive access to the file so using your normal file operations, you can't tell when the file is in use or not by another program that you do not control.

If you can know by observing that this other program that modifies the file modifies the file and then there's some amount of quiet time where it's not modifying the file before it modifies the file again (like it modifies the file no more frequently than every few minutes) and that looks like something you can rely on, then I can think of a hack.

What you would do is you'd have a nodejs program that runs all the time and watches the file of interest.  When, you see it change (by watching either the modification time or the file size or both), then you'd wait some prescribed amount of time to make sure the modifications are done (perhaps 10 seconds, based on the access pattern you observed by the program changing the files) and you'd quickly make a copy of the file to your own filename.  Your cron job running every 15 minutes can then use that copy of the file as a safe copy of the latest data that won't be modified while you are reading it.

For watching the file for modifications, you can either use your own code that polls the file stats every 30 seconds or so or you can use `fs.watch()` to dynamically watch the file for changes.  For making a copy of the file, you can use `fs.copyFile()`.